# Trying to Append Date and Time to Filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, date

I'm new to python and I'm trying to open a file titled `folder\YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM_filename.csv`

Here is the code I'm using:

```
date = 'folder\\' + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M") + '_filename.csv'
f = open(date, 'w')
...
```

When I print the first line it returns the filename and path that I want, but the second line throws the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'folder\\2019-03-13_10:57_filename.csv
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this error. I'm using Python 3.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is not a valid character for file names in Windows. You can use a different delimiter, such as `-`, for time instead:

```
date = 'folder\\' + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M") + '_filename.csv'
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using chars that can not exist in a file name

> : 
>   " 
>   / 
>   \ 
>   | 
>   ? 
>   * 
>   "`"

Comment: That's if you are using windows as your OS, The only Char not allowed in Linux is "/" .

Comment: Thanks, that was dumb of me.